# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipArchiveOutputStream

Tags: java, apache-poi

trying to read the data from .xlsx in linux, but having this error.

```
FAILED: readExcel
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipArchiveOutputStream
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:233)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:166)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.openPackage(POIXMLDocument.java:89)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:336)
    at com.admin.integration.manage.PolicyEnforcementTest.readExcel(PolicyEnforcementTest.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveOutputStream
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 30 more
```

This is my code which i tried, but not at all worked for me. Tried to add different jars added but not worked for me.

```
XSSFWorkbook srcBook = new XSSFWorkbook(util.getDownloadsPath() + util.getExcelFilePath());     
XSSFSheet sourceSheet = srcBook.getSheetAt(0);
int rownum=12;
XSSFRow sourceRow = sourceSheet.getRow(rownum);
XSSFCell cell1=sourceRow.getCell(0);
XSSFCell cell2=sourceRow.getCell(24);
```

Comment: It worked perfectly in windows machine, but failed in Ubuntu

Comment: As far as I know `XSSFWorkbook` is used only for excel. Ubuntu doesn't have excel.

Comment: The class `org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipArchiveOutputStream` is of Apache Commons Compress. So it lacks the `commons-compress-1.18.jar` in class path.

Comment: commons-compress-1.18.jar was there in the java build path.

Comment: A `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` only occurs if a class definition cannot be found on run time. In that concrete case it cannot find `*.class` file for `org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveOutputStream`. But `ZipArchiveOutputStream.class` file is contained in `commons-compress-1.18.jar` in directory `org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/`. So the error clearly states, that the JVM class loader has no accesss to `commons-compress-1.18.jar` at run time.